# No events appear in Tensorboard (r0.8 and r0.9) on Mac OS X

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Script (just simple linear regression line fitting):

```
import tensorflow as tf 
import numpy as np 

ITERS           = 25
N               = 5000
MINI_BATCH_SIZE = 500
LEARNING_RATE   = 0.001

# create dataset & sampling
X = np.random.randn(N)
Y = 0.5 * X + 0.3 * np.random.random(N)

def sample(X, Y, n=MINI_BATCH_SIZE):
    idx = np.random.choice(np.arange(X.shape[0]), n, replace=False)
    return X[idx], Y[idx]

session = tf.InteractiveSession()

# graph setup
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="x")
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None], name="y")
W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([]), trainable=True, name="slope")
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([]), trainable=True, name="bias")
prediction = W*x + b

# loss & training
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(y - prediction), name="l2_loss")
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE)
trainer = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# for tensorboard
for value in [loss, W, b]:
    print "Adding summaries for: %s" % value.op.name
    tf.scalar_summary(value.op.name, value)

summaries_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('./stats', session.graph)

# initialize and start
session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print "W: %s, b: %s" % (W.eval(), b.eval())

# train
for i in range(ITERS):
    x_batch, y_batch = sample(X, Y)
    feed = {x: x_batch, y: y_batch}
    trainer.run(feed_dict=feed)
    summary_str = summaries_op.eval(feed_dict=feed)
    summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
```

After I run it, there is a protobuf file in the `stats` directory, and I run `tensorboard`:

```
$ ls stats/
events.out.tfevents.1466477409.XXXXXXXXXX.local 

$ tensorboard --logdir=/Users/me/tensorflow/stats/ --debug
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard is in debug mode.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting TensorBoard in directory /Users/me/tensorflow
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard path_to_run is: {'/Users/me/tensorflow/stats/': None}
INFO:tensorflow:Adding events from directory /Users/me/tensorflow/stats/
INFO:tensorflow:Constructing EventAccumulator for /Users/me/tensorflow/stats/
DEBUG:tensorflow:Opening a record reader pointing at /Users/me/tensorflow/stats/events.out.tfevents.1466477409.XXXXXXXXXXX.local
DEBUG:tensorflow:No more events in /Users/me/tensorflow/stats/events.out.tfevents.1466477409.XXXXXXXXXXX.local
INFO:tensorflow:No path found after /Users/me/tensorflow/stats/events.out.tfevents.1466477409.XXXXXXXXXXX.local
DEBUG:tensorflow:No more events in /Users/me/tensorflow/stats/events.out.tfevents.1466477409.XXXXXXXXXXX.local
INFO:tensorflow:No path found after /Users/me/tensorflow/stats/events.out.tfevents.1466477409.XXXXXXXXXXX.local
INFO:tensorflow:Multiplexer done loading. Load took 0.0 secs
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard is tag: 16
Starting TensorBoard 16 on port 6006
```

Then when I navigate to the tensorboard, I see nothing:

[image: no events]

I've tried with both r0.9 and r0.8 with same results on Mac OS X; installed using pip & virtualenv.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to this issue ?

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1421

> @llevar, what worked for me is copying the global.css file from this
>   git repository to the location listed in the error log in your earlier
>   comment. That is, I copied global.css to where tensorboard was looking
>   for it on my system:
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/lib/css/.
>
> From your earlier comment, it looks like you might want to copy that
>   global.css file to the following location on your system:
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/lib/css/.
>   Also, you will probably need to create that css directory first.